# Nvarchar data type to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
INSERT INTO [std_Receipt]
           ([rcp_GUID]
           ,[rcp_Date]
           ,[rcp_Check_No]
           ,[rcp_Amount]
           --,[rcp_InterestRate]
           ,[rcp_Purpose]
           ,[rcp_Deposited]
           ,[rcp_Statement]
           ,[rcp_Note]
           ,[rcp_State]
           ,[rcp_Reconciled]
           ,[rcp_ForceItemize]
           ,[rcp_ForceUnitemize]
           ,[rcp_per_GUID]
           ,[rcp_rcs_GUID]
           ,[rcp_sou_GUID]
           ,[rcp_chs_GUID]
           ,[rcp_acc_GUID]
           ,[rcp_bat_GUID]
           ,[rcp_FecId]
           ,[rcp_TransId]
           --,[rcp_rlv_GUID]
           --,[rcp_let_GUID_ThankYou]
           --,[rcp_let_GUID_Compliance]
           --,[rcp_ple_GUID]
           --,[rcp_link_GUID]
           ,[rcp_Deleted]
           ,[rcp_CreatedOn]
           ,[rcp_CreatedBy]
           --,[rcp_UpdatedOn]
           --,[rcp_UpdatedBy]
           --,[rcp_DeletedOn]
           --,[rcp_DeletedBy]
           ,[rcp_Support]
           ,[rcp_Oppose]
           ,[rcp_SourceId]
           --,[rcp_DueDate]
           --,[rcp_MatchingFundsSequence]
           --,[rcp_receivedDate]
           ,[rcp_ReceivedYear]
           --,[rcp_TransferAmount]
           --,[rcp_YearPart]
           --,[rcp_AmendmentCode]
           ,[rcp_Locked]
           --,[rcp_LockedOn]
           --,[rcp_FillingId]
           --,[rcp_FillingDate]
           --,[rcp_pmt_GUID]
           --,[rcp_IsValid]
           --,[rcp_ReceivedBy_GUID]
           --,[rcp_ReceiptableAmount]
           --,[rcp_isNonReceiptable]
           --,[rcp_ReceiptSentDate]
           )
     select
           rcpguid,--(<rcp_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           date,--,<rcp_Date, datetime,>
           isnull(check_no,''),--,<rcp_Check_No, nvarchar(50),>
           amount,--,<rcp_Amount, money,>
           --,<rcp_InterestRate, decimal(9,6),>
           isnull(note,''),--,<rcp_Purpose, nvarchar(250),>
           deposited,--,<rcp_Deposited, datetime,>
           deposited,--,<rcp_Statement, datetime,>
           '',--,<rcp_Note, ntext,>
           '',--,<rcp_State, nchar(2),>
           0,--,<rcp_Reconciled, bit,>
           0,--,<rcp_ForceItemize, bit,>
           CASE WHEN [type] = 'Unitemized' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,--,<rcp_ForceUnitemize, bit,>
           perguid,--,<rcp_per_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           rcsguid,--,<rcp_rcs_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           souguid,--,<rcp_sou_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           chsguid,--,<rcp_chs_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           accguid,--,<rcp_acc_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           batguid,--,<rcp_bat_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           '',--,<rcp_FecId, nvarchar(20),>
           '',--,<rcp_TransId, nvarchar(20),>
           --,<rcp_rlv_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           --,<rcp_let_GUID_ThankYou, uniqueidentifier,>
           --,<rcp_let_GUID_Compliance, uniqueidentifier,>
           --,<rcp_ple_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           --,<rcp_link_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           0,--,<rcp_Deleted, bit,>
           getdate(),--,<rcp_CreatedOn, datetime,>
           '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',--,<rcp_CreatedBy, uniqueidentifier,>
           --,<rcp_UpdatedOn, datetime,>
           --,<rcp_UpdatedBy, uniqueidentifier,>
           --,<rcp_DeletedOn, datetime,>
           --,<rcp_DeletedBy, uniqueidentifier,>
           0,--,<rcp_Support, bit,>
           0,--,<rcp_Oppose, bit,>
           'CM:'+cast(keyid as nvarchar),--,<rcp_SourceId, nvarchar(10),>
           --,<rcp_DueDate, datetime,>
           --,<rcp_MatchingFundsSequence, bigint,>
           --,<rcp_receivedDate, datetime,>
           year(date),--,<rcp_ReceivedYear, varchar(4),>
           --,<rcp_TransferAmount, money,>
           --,<rcp_YearPart, int,>
           --,<rcp_AmendmentCode, nvarchar(3),>
           0--,<rcp_Locked, bit,>
           --,<rcp_LockedOn, datetime,>
           --,<rcp_FillingId, nvarchar(30),>
           --,<rcp_FillingDate, datetime,>
           --,<rcp_pmt_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           --,<rcp_IsValid, bit,>
           --,<rcp_ReceivedBy_GUID, uniqueidentifier,>
           --,<rcp_ReceiptableAmount, money,>
           --,<rcp_isNonReceiptable, bit,>
           --,<rcp_ReceiptSentDate, datetime,>)
   from i_contfile
```

Ok I am getting an error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

But pretty simple set up I am doing an insert of my receipts and not sure how to get around this..

Comment: Which column is a date/time data type that has a string being used for the insert?  That is probably a really good place to start.

Comment: The columns are correctly aligned and but all of the columns in i_contfile are NVARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

On first glance, the most likely cause of the error is bad data in the `i_contfile.date` column.  The other date is filled in by `GETDATE()` which should be fine.

What is the schema of the `i_contfile.date` column?  Is it an `NVARCHAR` column?

One way to locate the exact rows with the problem is to do a binary search.  INSERT the first half of the rows with a `BEGIN TRAN` / `ROLLBACK`.  If that succeeds, try the second half.  Keep narrowing down the rows until you find the one causing the issue.

Is it possible to do a `SELECT * FROM i_contfile` and include the results in your answer?

Another way I've seen this happen is with columns in the `SELECT` not matching the column order in the `INSERT`.  This does not look like the cause in this case.

It gets really tricky if a comma is missing, because then SQL Server treats the next column as a column alias of the prior column.  For example, the `SELECT` below appears to have 4 columns, but in reality it has only 3.  Without the comma, the `SELECT` results in renaming `ColB` to `ColC`.  This is an easy mistake on huge `INSERT` queries:

```
INSERT INTO Dest
(
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3
)
SELECT
    ColA,
    ColB  -- missing comma!
    ColC, -- this is now the alias of ColB
    ColD
FROM Source
```

-- UPDATE --

You said the input column was an `NVARCHAR` column.  You can check the validity of a date string with the [ISDATE function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO std_Receipt
(...rcp_Date...)
SELECT...
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(date) = 0 THEN NULL
         ELSE date
    END,
...
```

You could find bad date data in the `i_contfile` table fairly quickly with this technique:

```
SELECT *
FROM i_contfile
WHERE ISDATE(date) = 0
```

If the source date data has some custom formatting, we should be able to figure out how to handle the data once we see what the format is.

Comment: Well the file is much too large to do a select * from query but it is indeed a NVARCHAR column, is there a way to format them correclty?

Comment: You could check to see if the data is a valid date with the `ISDATE` function.  Updated the answer with more info.

Comment: No, nothing came back as bad data for the date type and the ISDATE did not work and comes back with the same error.

Comment: Maybe there is a different date column?  What is the schema of your std_Receipt table?

Comment: There is another date column - [Deposited] and it is showing my dates as '01991006'.

Comment: Initially I ran:                                                                                            update i_contfile set deposited = cast([date] as datetime) where deposited = '' - But didn't work still converted the same way

Comment: Is there invalid data in the Deposited column?  `SELECT * FROM i_contfile WHERE ISDATE(Deposited) = 0`